# Django JQuery $.load() загрузить в div html

Tags: jquery, python, django

Имеется шаблон `html`. Мне требуется в `div` загрузить шаблон при нажатии на ссылку.
На `php` реализация работает, а вот на `Django + JQuery` не работает увы.
Т.к мне нужно указать для `$('#test').load(my url)()` указать путь к `html` документу.
В `php` опять же — это было просто, а как на `Python Django` сделать?

Прим.код `JS` который юзал:

```js
function a() {
            //alert('fdsfsdfdsf');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#div-space').empty();
                $('#div-space').load('service1.html')().show('low');
            });
            //
        }
```

Comment: $('#div-space').html(путь к шаблону)

Comment: попробую сделать )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вы работаете с django, вам нужно определить в `urls.py` `url`, чтобы `Django` знал, как его обработать.

Если вас интересует какая-то конретная `view`, то нужно указать `url`, по которой она располагается.

Шаблоны `Django` и url'ы изначально никак не связаны (за исключением django.views.generic)

Пример решения вашей проблемы сможете найти [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201346/how-do-i-go-straight-to-template-in-djangos-urls-py)

[Документация urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/)

[Документация views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/)

Comment: Ознакомлюсь, отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо!) Все заработало, буду подтягивать мат.часть :)))